# HttpClient always return status code 200 on call from Xamarin class

Tags: php, xamarin, http-status-codes

I'm learning xamarin and php side by side and I'm stuck here because I'm not able to receive the right response from php and I know there's an error because I have intentionally misspelled the query.

I'm using XAMPP and Visual Studio 2017, my code in php looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('logger.php');
include('userobj.php');
$log = new Log("errors.log");


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
   $log->{'Write'}('Received a POST Request');
    try
    {

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        foreach($data as $key =>$value)
        {
            $log->{'Write'}("array key: " . $key . " array value: " . $value);
        }

        $user = new User($data);
        $log->{'Write'}("after createad: ");
        $user->{'CreateNewUser'}();

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        http_response_code("400");
        $log->{'Write'}("Error message\n"+$e->getMessage());
    }

}
else
{    
    $log->{'Write'}("REQUEST NOT A POST");
}


?>
```

I have tried using a Try/Catch inside php and I know it's getting the error because I'm able to write it to my log, the method that I'm calling look like this:

```
public function CreateNewUser()
    {
        try
        {
             global $log, $config;
            $log->{'Write'}("Creating Connection"); 
            $connection = mysqli_connect($config->db_host,$config->db_username,$config->db_pwd,$config->db_dbname);

            if($connection)
            {
                $log->{'Write'}("Creating new user");       
                $query = "INSERT INTOS users (name, lastname, policynumber, phone, email) ";
                $query .= "VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->lastname', '$this->policynumber', '$this->phone', '$this->email');";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if(!$result)
                {
                    $log->{'Write'}('Query Failed on Create New User: ');
                    $log->{'Write'}(mysqli_error($connection));
                    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $log->{'Write'}("Connection Failed");
                die('Connection Failed');
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            http_response_code("400");
            throw $e;
        }


    }
```

As I mentioned, I have misspelled the query to force an error... and finally my call from Xamarin c# looks like this:

```
public static async Task CreateUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {

                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
                var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content));
                string error = response.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

If I debug this code and see the value of the variable "response" it always has status code 200, I have seen similar issues but all of them using "GET".

Comment: have you tested your service with postman or a similar utility?

Comment: I just tried postman, I got Status 200 OK, however I can see an error in the text area of the software, the error is a message that I have wrote : "Query Failed, You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual....." it actually helped me to solve the problem, the problem was that I was storing the result of the query in a variable and using it on an if statement, thanks for letting me know about that great tool :)

Answer (score 0):

using postman as suggested by Jason in the comments helped me to see the issue, the problem is in this piece of code:

```
if($connection)
            {
                $log->{'Write'}("Creating new user");       
                $query = "INSERT INTOS users (name, lastname, policynumber, phone, email) ";
                $query .= "VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->lastname', '$this->policynumber', '$this->phone', '$this->email');";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if(!$result)
                {
                    $log->{'Write'}('Query Failed on Create New User: ');
                    $log->{'Write'}(mysqli_error($connection));
                    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }
            }
```

The problem was that I have stored the result of the query in a variable called $result and then I have used it in a if statement, so I have updated the code to this:

```
if(!$result)
                {
                    $log->{'Write'}('Query Failed on Create New User: ');
                    $log->{'Write'}(mysqli_error($connection));
                    http_response_code(500); //This line returns the response code 500
                    die('Query Failed ' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }
```

I was not able to see this behaviour during a call from a mobile device, so using 'Postman' was very useful.